# MachineKey.Encode is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am trying to encrypt a cookie in asp.net 4.0 with Machine.Encode method but I am getting compilation error.The error is at line "Response.Cookies.Add". What is correct method?

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.Web.HttpCookie'    Error  1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.HttpCookieCollection.Add(System.Web.HttpCookie)' has some
>   invalid arguments

```
public static string MachEncrypt (string plaintextValue)
{
    var plaintextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (plaintextValue);
    return MachineKey.Encode (plaintextBytes, MachineKeyProtection.All);
}

public static string MachDecrypt (string encryptedValue)
{
    try
    {
        var decryptedBytes = MachineKey.Decode (encryptedValue, MachineKeyProtection.All);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString (decryptedBytes);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}

HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("co");
myCookie.Values.Add("customerId", dr["customerId"].ToString());
if (chkRemember.Checked)
{
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
}   
Response.Cookies.Add(StringEncryptor.MachEncrypt(myCookie.ToString()));
```

Comment: What is confusing about the error you have?

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: `MachineKey.Encode` can create security holes.  You must read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/10/22/cryptographic-improvements-in-asp-net-4-5-pt-1.aspx

Comment: @ayha you probably mean to encrypt the customerId.

Comment: that what you need http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Comment: @TimurShahbanov: That has nothing to do with this problem.  Also, don't trust a random non-HTTPS website to generate encryption keys.

Comment: Its help me a lot to stop per server requests auto logout

Comment: @MikeSmithDev, I am trying to encrypt http cookie. what is the correct method to do this?

Comment: @TimurShahbanov: Yes, but that has _nothing_ to do with this problem.    Also, you'd better hope that no-one intercepted your connection when you got that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error *clearly* states, `Cookies.Add()` takes an `HttpCookie` object, not a string.

You need to construct an `HttpCookie` with your ciphertext, as well as any options for the cookie (such as `Secure` or `HttpOnly`).